# Cauchy Product of Two Divergent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-product

**Problem**

Examine the following Cauchy product and the factors for convergence and in the case of convergence determine the limit.

$$\left(3 + \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}3^k\right)\left(-2+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}2^k\right)$$

**My Answer**

The two factors $(3+\sum3^k)$ and $(-2+\sum 2^k)$ diverges (by for example the fact that the limit of the summand is clearly not $0$). And similarly, the whole product diverges as well (since both factors diverges to positive infinity).

Edit: I just checked Wolfram Alpha and it confirms all my answers. Maybe the question itself is just silly.

I think I'm just confused because I don't think the supposed answer should be this simple. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks that simple to me.

Comment: Well, I suppose I'll run with it then.